# How to reverse the order of rows when Importing a csv file into Excel

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I want to import a multicolumn `.csv` file into Excel. But my aim is to import them with reversed order; e.g. I want the last row of the `.csv` file be the first in my Excel and the first row of the `.csv` file be the last row in my Excel. I like something like a macro or an advanced filter for this task.

My `.csv` contains around 14000 rows so I can't use any manual tricks.

Comment: The question as presented shows no effort by the OP to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Import data in usual way
2. Add/insert an extra column to the imported data
3. Populate the extra column using Series Fill so that it contains the values 1,2,3,...
4. Select all data (imported and the extra column) and sort on the values in the extra column in descending order
5. Delete the extra column - data will now be sorted as you require.

Comment: This excellent idea could be recorded into a reusable macro with only mild tweaking.

Comment: But as I already mentioned in my question, I can't do such manual stuff each time I'm importing a csv file. I need something like a macro to do this automatically!

Comment: Don't see why you shouldn't do this manually. The only difficult part for a manual operation is Step 3, where you have to select the rows of the extra column that correspond to your data before using the Series Fill operation (Fill button, Editing group, Home tab). That's easy if the extra column is inserted as Col A and data starts in Col B. Type 1 in  A1;select B1; {end} {down} {left} puts you in last cell of Col A; {shift} {end} {up} selects all cells in A; {Fill} {Series} {OK} populates A. And, as Jerry B notes whole sequence of all 5 steps could be automated using the macro recorder.

Comment: For a one-time import I agree that the manual solution is sufficient. But for the case where the source csv gets new rows added to the top and needs to be repeatedly refreshed in Excel (e.g., the way my bank formats the transaction list), I think that the manual solution could be unwieldy and error-prone.

Comment: The appropriateness of any solution will, of course,  depend on the precise details of your use case and any limitations imposed by the source that generates the csv. I maintain a master list of bank transactions in oldest first order. Periodically, I download a csv of bank transactions comprising those after the last one on the master but these are, inconveniently, presented in most recent first order. I simply reverse the order of the transactions on the csv using the technique set out above on a separate worksheet before appending them to the end of the master list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set up the imported CSV such that the rows remain in reverse order even when you refresh the data connection.

1. Import the CSV as a data connection. 
    [image: import csv]
2. Click Transform Data. 
    [image: click transform]
3. Add an "Index Column". The starting number is your choice. 
    [image: add index column]
4. Sort the new column in Descending order. 
    [image: sort descending]
5. Click "Close & Load". 
    [image: close and load]